# mysql exclude results with same id in two tables

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have a working query that fetches some results.

```
    $sql = "
        SELECT 
            swdl.wedding_dress AS wedding_dress,
            wd.name AS name,
            wdi.url AS image
        FROM salons_wedding_dresses_link AS swdl 
            LEFT JOIN wedding_dresses AS wd ON swdl.wedding_dress = wd.id
            LEFT JOIN wedding_dress_images AS wdi ON wdi.wedding_dress = wd.id AND wdi.main_image = 1    
            WHERE swdl.salon = ? AND wd.active = 1
    ";
```

What i want is to update it to only fetch results where `wedding_dress` in table `salons_wedding_dresses_link` is not located in table `wedding_dress_dress_collection_link` in column `wedding_dress_id` but i fail to do so.
[image]
Bellow is the updated query, with update in bold.

```
            $sql = "
        SELECT 
            swdl.wedding_dress AS wedding_dress,
            wd.name AS name,
            wdi.url AS image
        FROM salons_wedding_dresses_link AS swdl 


LEFT JOIN wedding_dress_dress_collection_link AS wddcl
------------------------------------------------------

            LEFT JOIN wedding_dresses AS wd ON swdl.wedding_dress = wd.id
            LEFT JOIN wedding_dress_images AS wdi ON wdi.wedding_dress = wd.id AND wdi.main_image = 1    
            WHERE 

swdl.wedding_dress NOT IN (SELECT wddcl.wedding_dress_id FROM wddcl) AND
------------------------------------------------------------------------



swdl.salon = ? AND wd.active = 1
        ";
```

Comment: Ok, so do you understand the joins in your query? if so, what do you think you would do to exclude lines that don't have a matching id in the salons_wedding_dress_link table?

Comment: No sorry, not well enough, i am front end developer :) i am trying some stuff out :)

Comment: Well, SQL for the most part is pretty readable, so a LEFT join takes all stuff on the left, and whatevers on the right that matches...how about now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select query to get the result which is present in `salons_wedding_dresses_link` but not in `wedding_dress_dress_collection_link`:

```
 select s1.*,s2.wedding_dress_collection_id,s2.wedding_dress_id  
 from salons_wedding_dresses_link s1
 left join wedding_dress_dress_collection_link s2 on
 s1.wedding_dress=s2.wedding_dress_id 
 whrere s2.wedding_dress_id  is null;
```